# Slow/Stuttered scroll in tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm loading about 150 elements from an array of arrays of dictionaries (`tasks`) and I can get all of the data into my tableview but when I scroll its stupid slow. When I print out the information of one of my functions to the console, it looks like I am getting all of the data back every time I scroll. Is this something I am not loading well (i.e. asynchronously) or do I need to change my functions?

```
    func querySections() -> [String] {
        var sectionsArray = [String]()
        for task in tasks {
            let dueTimes = task.dueTime
            sectionsArray.append(dueTimes)
        }
        let uniqueSectionsArray = Array(Set(sectionsArray.sort()))
//        print(uniqueSectionsArray)
        return uniqueSectionsArray
    }


    func queryDueTimes(section:Int) -> [Task] {
        var sectionItems = [Task]()
        for task in tasks {
            let dueTimes = task.dueTime
            if dueTimes == querySections()[section] {
                sectionItems.append(task)
            }
        }
        print(sectionItems)
        return sectionItems
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return querySections()[section]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return querySections().count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return queryDueTimes(section).count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let times = queryDueTimes(indexPath.section)
        let task = times[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = task.title
        if task.done == true {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(task.completedBy)"
            }
            else {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = ""
            }

        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Basically, in `querySections`, I'm iterating through all of the dueTimes for each task and then changing them into an array of a set so I can filter out all of the duplicates. This is giving me all of my sections. For `queryDueTimes`, I'm iterating through the tasks and matching them to a section.

I had a thought about calling the functions in `viewDidLoad` but that isn't working (it keeps giving me an empty array when I try to pass it to another empty array thats more accessible outside of the function) and I can't access section (for `queryDueTimes`) in viewDidLoad (as far as what I know how to do).

**Update 1:**
I think the mistake is on my end. I said that I tasks is an array of arrays when its just an array of Tasks (a struct with all of the properties of each task). When I load the app, I append all of the tasks from my backend to a local array ("tasks"). Should I have an array of arrays for this to work or can I amend my code somehow and get it to work?

**Update 2:**

I'm getting `sectionTimes` and `tasksInSectionArray` as empty arrays when I print them.

```
    var sectionTimes = [String]()
    var tasksInSectionArray = [[Task]]()
    var tasks = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func updateTableView() {
            sectionTimes = Set(tasks.map{$0.dueTime}).sort()
            tasksInSectionArray = sectionTimes.map{section in tasks.filter{$0.dueTime == section}}
            print(sectionTimes)
            print(tasksInSectionArray)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return sectionTimes[section]
        }

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return sectionTimes.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return tasksInSectionArray[section].count
        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

            // Configure the cell...
            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            let task = tasksInSectionArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Don't guess. Don't speculate. Use Instruments! It will tell you exactly what's taking up the time during the scroll. Then you'll _know_ where to focus your attention.

Comment: I'm still not really even sure how to use that. I'm still very new to developing with Swift for iOS. Can you help me by providing a step or two in the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like DMan is solving your problem by eyeballing it. That's bad because it would have been better for you to learn to use Instruments! :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sections: [String] = []
var data: [[Tasks]] = []

func updateTableView() {
    sections = Set(tasks.map { $0.dueTime }).sort()
    data = sections.map { section in tasks.filter { $0.dueTime == section } }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let task = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    // Cell configuration
}
```

This is basically what DMan said, but I've made an example for you.

Comment: This might not be exactly what you want, so you might have to sort it to your own liking. But generally this should speed it up.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still really new at this. Maybe I communicated wrongly because I am getting an error. On line 2 of updateTableView() (data=...) I'm getting an error that it cannot convert [Task] to the closure result type of Task.

Comment: Don't be sorry. Everyone makes mistakes and I should be the one to be sorry because I made a mistake :p. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: See my update...
Your solution is correct with what I gave you initially (I was a bit confused as to what I had at first). Would it be helpful to include more of my code?

Comment: To answer your edit: If you want multiple sections, the "easiest" way is to have a 2 dimensional Array, e.g. Array of an Array. You could create a dictionary instead or calculate it manually every time like you did before but as you've noticed that's not efficient. Is my answer giving another error? Or is there another reason it's not working?

Comment: its not throwing an error. its not really doing anything anymore. see update 2 for my attempt at creating a 2 dimensional array and using that.

Comment: Can you update the code you have now in your question so I can try to figure out what's wrong? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107189/discussion-between-michael-williams-and-eendje).

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to call updateTableView in the didSet property of tasks not in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 3):

Like you guessed, the data is being loaded and sorted over and over again, instead of only once. Save the results of `querySelections` and `queryDueTimes` and use that inside the table view data source methods.

You can do this in `viewDidLoad` - call both functions once and assign the results to a variable at the class level, and then call `tableView.reloadData()` (assuming you have a reference to the table view).

Comment: I think I've tried this before because I'm hitting a familiar bump. When I get down to cellForRow, I end up with a problem at the first couple lines of code. let times and let tasks. I can assign times to sectionTimes[indexPath.section] (sectionTimes is at class level) but I can't assign tasks to times[indexPath.row].